# Java: problems using stream to read a file

Tags: java, file, split, path, stream

using what has been previously suggested to me here, I'm trying to read a file using Path and streams in the following way:

```
Path p= Paths.get(file);
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(p, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) { // 1
            lines.map(line -> line.split(";"))                          // 2
                 .forEach(lineAsArray -> {
                     if (lineAsArray[0].equals("E")) {
                         creaEditore(lineAsArray[2], Integer.parseInt(lineAsArray[3]), lineAsArray[4]);
                     }
                     else if (lineAsArray[0].equals("L")) {
                        Libro tmp = null;
                        try {
                            tmp = creaLibro(lineAsArray[1], lineAsArray[2], Integer.parseInt(lineAsArray[3]), Double.parseDouble(lineAsArray[4]), lineAsArray[5]);
                        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (EditoreInesistente e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        tmp.setQuantita(Integer.parseInt(lineAsArray[6]));
                     }
                 });
        }
        catch (IOException io)
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong reading");
        }
```

Each line contains at the beginning a letter that corresponds to the object I want to create (either an "Editore" or a "Libro") and the following fields contains the value of its attributes (all fields are separated by a semi-column). However, when executing, I get the following exceptions and errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "cheih@gja.it"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at libreria.Libreria.lambda$4(Libreria.java:122)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at libreria.Libreria.leggi(Libreria.java:120)
    at Esempio.main(Esempio.java:20)
```

Debugging I discovered that everything is perfectly working when reading the first line, but then the program is not able to parse it and get each field using lineAsArray[]. Can someone help me? The requirements of the program also asked for not considering lines with incorrect sintax, would my code do something like that automatically?

Here the sintax of my file:

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help,
Gianluca.

Comment: Are you sure about the indexes, don't you mean `creaEditore(lineAsArray[1], Integer.parseInt(lineAsArray[2]), lineAsArray[3]);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your case is E, your code is following

```
if (lineAsArray[0].equals("E")) {
   creaEditore(lineAsArray[2], Integer.parseInt(lineAsArray[3]), lineAsArray[4]);
   }
```

And you are trying to convert value of **lineAsArray[3] into Int**.
In this case value at index 3 is "**cheih@gja.it**" which cannot be converted to int. Which is why you are getting this exception

Comment: You saved my day thank you. Any idea to avoid considering lines with incorrect sintax?

Comment: There are many ways to store and retrieve data, as if you want to save data in file you should use JSON. its easy to read and store data in JSON format . or you could use database either file based DB e.g. H2 or MySql for big projcet

Comment: @Gianluca there is no wrong syntax involved, check your code carefully!

Comment: ok, but I still don't get how I can ignore line with incorrect sintax, for example line starting with an "X" using this way of reading. I thought it would automatically discard them because this case is not one of the "if else if" statement, but I get errors....

Comment: @Gianluca which errors do you get? Sincd your statement is correct (lines with incorrect prefixes are ignored), it means there must be a problem elsewhere.but without the error/stacktrace its impossible to point in a right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I think you made a little misstake in the first part. E.g.

```
if (lineAsArray[0].equals("E")) {
creaEditore(lineAsArray[2], Integer.parseInt(lineAsArray[3]), lineAsArray[4]);
}
```

Notice how you jumped from index '0' (in the if statement) to index '2' (in the first argument of "creaEditore"). If it wouldnt complain about the wrong argument in the "parseInt" method, this would throw an IndexOutOfBoundException because array indexing starts at 0 instead of 1.